# if $variable1 is greater than $variable2 break and continue

Tags: php

I need to break the loop if the $variable1 is greater than 657246 Then continue the loop array

Something like this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($out[0]);$i++){

$variable1 = "$z->extract('<postid-','>',$data);"

   if (**sentence**) {
       continue; // Don't continue the sentences below and continue the next value from the loop
   }

}
```

Comment: You want to break and then continue from where you broke? Explain a little bit more please

Comment: Continue goes to the top of the loop, break stops the loop alltogether

Comment: This don't make no sense.

Comment: perhaps he wants a GOTO() :-)

Comment: `break` and `continue` are two different keywords that do two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errr. From what I gather, you are just looking to skip the current loop if $variable1 is greater than 657246 (random number btw?).

If so you were on the right track with continue.

```
if ($variable1 > 657246) {
     continue; 
}
```

Or if you wanted to only run what is inside the loop if it is greater then

```
if ($variable1 <= 657246) {
     continue; 
}
```

[Continue](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) ends the **current loop** and starts again from the top.
[Break](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) ends the **entire loop structure** and runs from the closing } of the loop.

Or, as the manual puts it:

> **continue** is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.
>
> **break** ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or
>   switch structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do.. but if I understood correctly, you could just use a boolean.

```
$toContinue = true;
for($i=0;$i<count($out[0]);$i++){

$variable1 = "$z->extract('<postid-','>',$data);"

   if (**sentence**) {
      $toContinue = false;
   }

   if($toContinue){
      //more sentences php
      //more sentences php
      //more sentences php
      //more sentences php
   }
   $toContinue = true;

}
```